# JSON Response Comparison with limited data

Tags: android, json

I have a edit text in login page, and I have a condition for edit text MaxLength="12". In my JSON response I have a string with 15 letters (or Nor's), I need to check (or compare) up to 12 letters(or Nor's) from it, If both letters are same up to 12 Letter(or Nor's), then I have to enter into my app.

```
{
ID No="123456789012.00"
}
```

Comment: Hello @suresh did you get help from any answer?

Answer (score 3):

Hello Suresh Use `String#substring`

```
  try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("{\"id_no\":\"123456789012.00\"}");
        String strJNumber = jObj.optString("id_no").substring(0,11);
        String strENumber = etNumber.getText().toString();

        if(strENumber.equals(strJNumber)){
            // TODO: true both are same   
        }else {
            // TODO: true both are not same
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "substring" and "equals" methods:
(I assume your strings' names are editTextString and jsonString)

First, get substring of first 12 chars from json string:

```
String jsonFirst12Chars = jsonString.substring(0,12);
```

Then use equals method to compare them:

```
if(editTextString.equals(jsonFirst12Chars)) {
// They are same, do something
} else {
// They are not same..
}
```